# kubectl not found error in jenkins pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, kubectl, jenkins-job-dsl

```
stage('Deploy Test chart') {
      steps{
        container('ubuntu-kubectl-helm') {
           script {
                  kubeconfig(credentialsId: 'kubeconfig-test'){
                    sh "which kubectl"
                    sh "kubectl config view"
                    sh "kubectl get nodes"
                    sh "kubectl get pods -n jenkins-new"
                    sh "kubectl get pods -n test"
           }
            }
        }
       }
    }
```

We have 3 containers to run the whole pipeline. and we create an Ubuntu container to run Kubernetes on it(we have install kubectl on it). when we run this step as a part of the whole pipe line. It gives us errors.

```
ERROR: Failed to run "kubectl version". Returned status code 127.
stdout:
sh: 47: kubectl: not found
```

But when we run this step separately as a pipeline, then the pipeline is working and we get the results.Now we are stuck and not able to figure out how to proceed further.

We also checked the environment path and checked if it was running on the Ubuntu container or not.

Comment: It is most likely, that the error has something to do with env paths and execution context. I would manually add the `kubectl` path to the `PATH` or use absolute paths to refer to `kubectl`. This would help you troubleshoot.

Comment: attempted to do so, but received the same error

Answer (score 0):

Inside Jenkins you need to install kubectl. Same if you want to use docker in your pipeline.

Here my Dockerfile which does it.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

ARG HOST_UID=1004
ARG HOST_GID=999

USER root
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add - && \
    add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") $(lsb_release -cs) stable" && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose  \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose  \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose \
    && curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - 
RUN echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list \
    && apt-get -y update \
    && apt install -y kubectl

RUN usermod -u $HOST_UID jenkins
RUN groupmod -g $HOST_GID docker
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins
```